# Regression of arbitrary equations

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I am looking for something like a linear regression but instead of the equation being linear it can be completely arbitrary.

e.g.

For the equation of gravity, we already know $F = \frac{G m_1 m_2 }{ r^2}$

What I want is to feed an algorithm with a tabular set of values like this

$
\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
F & m_1 & m_2 & r \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
5 & 2 & 5 & 4 \\
1 & 3 & 2 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 5 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$

and it should try to predict the equation to the best of its abilities.

What is this form of regression called? Is there any algorithm that exists, which I can use?

Comment: The situation is not sufficiently specified. There are different possible "forms of regression" that might apply, depending on your model for the variation about the model; which variables have 'error', whether the variation is constant or related to the mean, and even on the form of the conditional distribution of the response.

Comment: We are trying to predict the model from a set of data. No assumptions are made. For starters lets assume there are no errors. All variables in RHS are independent.

Comment: If there are no errors and the function can be completely arbitrary, this is easy: the function is the mapping that you’ve just written down in the form of that table.

Comment: I mean, I need an algorithm that can fit the function.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want an algorithm that takes as input features m_1, m_2, r and the prediction target is F. In this case you can train a decision tree regressor, which can perfectly predict your target in the training sample. Note though that you usually do not want to have an estimator with a perfect training fit, because this estimator is likely to predict poorly on unseen data due to overfitting.

Comment: The decision tree model is not interpret-able as a nice and clean equation like the equation given by linear regression.

Comment: You said the function can be completely arbitrary, and you don't want to make any assumptions.  Now you're saying the function has to be "interpretable" and "nice and clean".  These requirements are conflicting.

Comment: Apparently, you want to use a linear model to approximate your function F, even though you do not specify this in your question. You can achieve this by using a polynomial regression. You may want to take a look at this resource https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_polynomial_interpolation.html

Comment: $F = \frac{G m_1 m_2 }{ r^2}$ is not a polynomial

Comment: I am familiar with the terms "equation search" or "function finder" in the context of your question. My open source curve and surface fitting web site zunzun.com has a function finder that might do what you are looking for. The function finder is at http://zunzun.com/FunctionFinder__A___/2/ and comes with example data for testing.

Comment: If there were no errors you don't need statistics at all; the only possible unknown in the equation is G (since you have data on the rest and they have no error). Take any row from your data set and compute $Fr^2/(m_1m_2)$ (it won't matter which row you choose since they are all free of error) and you will compute the *exact* value of $G$. (The fact that they *don't* give the same value of G makes it obvious the claim is false; either you should not assert what many pairs of rows from your data will deny or you should make sure your data agree with the assertion.)